# Get data from polymorphic relations with namespaces

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, namespaces, polymorphic-associations

I have a comments table that have comments of articles, recipes and products. So its a `polymorphic` relation. I have two columns `rel_id and rel_type` in my comments table those are being used for this relation.

Now in my `Comment.php` I have following relation

```
public function rel()
{
    $this->morphTo();
}
```

And in my other all classes I have following

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Comment', 'rel');
}
```

When I try to get owner of comment and all its related data I found class not found error. For example

```
$comments = Comment::find(1);
echo $comments->rel_type //article
```

Now if I want to get data of article and when I try

```
$comments->rel
```

I found `article class not found`. I am using namespace `App\Models\Article` I have searched it out I found answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866020/laravel-returning-the-namespaced-owner-of-a-polymorphic-relation). When I try accepted answer, nothing happens, error remains same. When I try second answer of same question, I found

```
 Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

My ultimate goal is to get comment owner data like $comments->articles->id and so on. Please guide how can I do that?

Comment: please post your database layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a blog post about this:

http://andrew.cool/blog/61/Morph-relationships-with-namespaces

There are a couple things you need to do. First, for all of your models that have comments, add the `$morphClass` variable to the class, e.g.:

```
class Photo {
    protected $morphClass = 'photo';
}
class Album {
    protected $morphClass = 'album';
}
```

Second, on the Comment class, define an array called `$rel_types` on your Comment class. This will be basically the inverse of what you just did, it's a mapping from short name to full class name.

```
class Comment {
    protected $rel_types = [
        'album' => \App\Album::class,
        'photo' => \App\Photo::class,
    ];
}
```

Finally, define an accessor for the `rel_type` column. This accessor will first retrieve the column from the database ("album", "photo", etc.) and then convert it to the full class name ("\App\Album", "\App\Photo", etc.)

```
/**
 * @param  string  $type  short name
 * @return string  full class name
 */
public function getRelTypeAttribute($type)
{
    if ($type === null) {
        return null;
    }

    $type = strtolower($type);
    return array_get($this->rel_types, $type, $type);
}
```

---

Note: `$morphClass` is something Laravel actually defines, so it has to be named that. `$rel_types` can be named anything you want, I just based it off of the `rel_type` column you have.

To make this even better, add that `getRelTypeAttribute` method to a trait so that any model that morphs can reuse that trait and method.

Comment: actually the point that I am not getting is that following your method I get `string(18) "app\models\article" ` that is class string not object. So let say `$comment = Comment::find(1)` has `rel_type article and rel_id 1`. so now how can I get article data like all attributes of article from article table that belongs to this comment.

Comment: @user1272333 Just use `$comment->rel` as you were before. The problem you faced earlier was that rel_type was just "article" and it tried to create a new object of class "article" which doesn't exist. Now, rel_type is "app\models\article" and it will successfully create an object of that full class name.

Comment: When I try `$comment->rel` it gives me error `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`

Comment: Because `$comment->rel()` is returning null. Why it is returning null?

Comment: Hi, its fixed because I was doing a blunder while doing morphTo as I wasn't using return statement. Thanks you solutions worked.

Comment: @user1272333 ok great, I should have noticed that in your question, glad you caught it