# How to manually set the value that is stored in model type column in polymorphic relations?

Tags: laravel, polymorphic-associations

Consider the following tables:

```
staff
    id - integer
    name - string

products
    id - integer
    price - integer

photos
    id - integer
    path - string
    imageable_id - integer
    imageable_type - string
```

Laravel by default stores the name of model class in `imageable_type` column .e.g `App\Product` and `App\Staff`. How to manually set the type values? e.g. `product` and `staff`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Laravel >= 5.1.14, you should set the static `Relation::morphMap` property to define all morph classes for your application.

In the `boot()` method of your `AppServiceProvider`, add the following:

```
\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation::morphMap([
    'product' => 'App\Product ',
    'staff' => 'App\Staff ',
]);
```

---

If using Laravel < 5.1.14, the `morphMap` functionality doesn't exist. However, you can set the `morphClass` attribute on the model. This will let you set the value that is used inside the `*_type` field.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $morphClass = 'product';
}

class Staff extends Model
{
    protected $morphClass = 'staff';
}
```

The issue with this approach, however, is that you won't be able to get the parent record from the morphed record. So, if you have a Product or Staff model, you'll be able to get the Photo just fine. But, if you have a Photo model, you won't be able to get the related Product or Staff record that easily. The issue and the solution to the issue are described [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866020/laravel-returning-the-namespaced-owner-of-a-polymorphic-relation?rq=1).

The `morphMap` functionality provided in Laravel >= 5.1.14 does not have this issue.

Comment: After 4 years there's now a better solution: in AppServiceProvider Relation::morphMap([ 'product' => 'App\Product ]);

Comment: @soundwave1337 `morphMap` has been around for a while. It was introduced into 5.1.14 via [PR #9891](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/9891).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you'll want to do that but, looking at the signature of the method of `MorphMany()` : https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_morphMany

`MorphMany morphMany(string $related, string $name, string $type = null, string $id = null, string $localKey = null)`

You can change the $type string.

Comment: He doesn't want to change the field name, but the value stored in it.