# Laravel polymorphic relationships with custom keys

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I'm having some problems getting a Polymorphic Relation to work in Laravel

**Tables**

```
Vacations
    id
    name

Posts
    id
    name

Images
    id
    type_id
    type
```

`Images.type_id` links to `posts.id` or `vacations.id`
`Images.type` is either `post` or `vacation`

Posts and Vacations can have many images but each image belongs to only 1 Post or Vacation.

**Vacation Model**

```
namespace App;

use App\Vacation;

class Vacation extends Model
{
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Image', 'imageable', 'type', 'type_id');
    }
}
```

**Image Model**

```
namespace App;

use App\Image;

class Image extends Model
{
    public function imageable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get an empty array but there are matching records.

```
$vacation = Vacation::find(1);
dd($vacation->images);
```

I can see Laravel is trying to run:

```
select * from `images` where `images`.`type_id` = 1 
and `images`.`type_id` is not null 
and `images`.`type` = App\Vacation
```

**When I run this "raw" and replace `"App\Vacation"` with `vacation` then I get my results.**

Is it normal it's passing the namespaced class name to the raw sql query?

I've tried changing the `Images.type` value from plural to singular but it still fails.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: this is Laravel 5.4, the most recent version afaik.

Comment: You don't need those: `use App\Image;` and `use App\Vacation;`. Which version of laravel is this?

Comment: 5.4 and removing the Use statements makes no difference.

Comment: how you store the images of the vacation.

Comment: @AmeerSalahAldeen the basic structure is in my post: images.id, images.type_id (links to the id of the vacation) and the images.type is "vacation", "post", etc.

Comment: @stef Yeah, I was only pointing it. Are your all table names `lowercase`?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova yes all lowercase table names

Comment: check this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866020/laravel-returning-the-namespaced-owner-of-a-polymorphic-relation

Comment: Can you confirm in your `images.type` column is stored `App\Vacation`?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova not sure what you mean? ìmages.type`is not in the vacation table or model, it's a column in the images table.

Comment: Yes, and what's in this column? It should store the name of the model **including** the namespace.

Comment: How are you storing your images? Where do you create them?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova wow that's weird. I had no idea the namespace had to be included. This fixes the issue of course. Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `images`, your column `type` should contain the model name, in your case either `App\Vacation` or `App\Post`.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

For what it's worth, it's possible to achieve what you want without having to update your database.

I had the same issue with a legacy database, and I fixed it by adding the following to `bootstrap/app.php`.

```
\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation::morphMap([
    'vacation' => \App\Vacation::class,
    'post' => \App\Post::class
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, you save my day. I was using old Eloquent `morphTo(...)` override with `getPolymorphicTypeAttribute($type)`. But it couldn't handle the Type with `morphedByMany`.

Comment: For what it is worth it is recommended that you put this boot function of your AppServiceProvider. You may register the morphMap in the boot function of your AppServiceProvider or create a separate service provider if you wish. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Answer (score 0):

add to vacation class 
this line 
        `protected $morphClass = 'vacation';`

if you want to sore the model name as vacation